# Memory leak using shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

Both code examples compile and run without problems. 
Using the second variant results in a memory leak. Any ideas why? 
Thanks in advance for any help.

Variant 1:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<ParameterTabelle> SpParameterTabelle;

struct ParTabSpalteData
{
      ParTabSpalteData(const SpParameterTabelle& tabelle, const string& id)
            :Tabelle(tabelle), Id(id)
      {

      }

      const SpParameterTabelle& Tabelle;
      string Id;
};
```

Variant 2:

```
struct ParTabSpalteData
{
      ParTabSpalteData(const SpParameterTabelle& tabelle, const string& id)
            :Id(id)
      {
            // causes memory leak
            Tabelle2 = tabelle;
      }

      SpParameterTabelle Tabelle2;
      string Id;
};
```

Comment: how did you determine that there is a leak ?

Comment: @Hassan: my IDE (Visual Studio 2008) has a memory leak detection, showing adresses of leaked memory areas in console after program exit. The leaks console output is gone if I use variant one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you checked, that you do not have cyclic shared pointer references?

For example:

```
class A {
  public: shared_ptr<A> x;
};

shared_ptr<A> a1(new A());
shared_ptr<A> a2(new A());
a1->x = a2;
a2->x = a1;
```

Here a1 and a2 will never be released, because they have pointers to each other which keeps them alive.

So in your case check if `SpParameterTabelle` has a reference on `ParTabSpalteData` or if there is another possibility to get a cyclic reference.

Comment: I was thinking that it might be such an issue. But I think example 1 should exhibit the same behaviour no ? or will it not because it is a reference rather than a shared_ptr itself ?

Comment: Yes, I checked and wasn't able to find any cycles.
I thought that perhaps the assignment of a const shared_ptr& to a shared_ptr in the constructor of variant two is causing the problem, but can't find an explanation...

Comment: By using a const& on the pointer, the shared_ptr does not increase its use count. If you issue a copy like in case 2, it does. So there is probably a cycle somewhere...

Comment: @nabulke Perhaps you should try to recreate a minimal instance of the  problem so we can compile it ?

Comment: Rule of thumb I guess, taking a reference or pointer of a smart pointer is subverting the purpose of said smart pointer

Comment: I personally find typedef confusing. It makes diagnosing problems like this quite different as it just obfuscates code.

Answer (score 0):

Note that passing a smart pointer as const SpParameterTabelle& tabelle do not forbid you to change the pointee object.

Have you tried passing directly the smart pointer, as

```
struct ParTabSpalteData
{
      ParTabSpalteData(SpParameterTabelle tabelle, const string& id)
            :Tabelle2(tabelle), Id(id)
      {
      }

      SpParameterTabelle Tabelle2;
      string Id;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Output something in the destructor of ParameterTabelle (trace/fileout), or set a breakpoint there. Does it really not get called twice?

I recently upgraded a VS2005 project to VS2010 and suddenly VS2010 reported memory leaks in boost::lexical_cast. And not in all of them, just in one single module on a single line - there were even other lexical_cast of the same type/other types all around in that file.

Even local memory state tests reported this as memory leak (code for debug mode only):

```
void run_stream_tests(std::ofstream& out)
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
  CMemoryState preState;
  preState.Checkpoint();
#endif
  {
    ...your code...
  }
#ifdef _DEBUG
  CMemoryState postState;
  postState.Checkpoint();
  CMemoryState diffState;
  if( diffState.Difference( preState, postState ) )
  {
    TRACE("Memory leaked!\n");
    preState.DumpAllObjectsSince();
  }
#endif
}
```

So, this could also be a VS2010/VS2008 problem.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Considerung this I will use Boundschecker or Purify to get a second opinion concerning the memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

There's also possibility that Visual Studio's memory leak detection is buggy.