# Why does Circular Reference cause Indirect Leak?

Tags: c++

From other questions on stackoverflow, I know that circular reference could cause leak, particularly indirect leaks:

[Memory leak using shared_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735982/memory-leak-using-shared-ptr)
[Possible Memory-leaks with smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38298008/possible-memory-leaks-with-smart-pointers)

I want to follow up the issue in more details. I made the following program to illustrate the scenario:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std; 

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass()                                         { cout<<"Default constructor"<<endl; }
    MyClass(MyClass const& s)                         { cout<<"Copy constructor"<<endl; }
    MyClass(MyClass&& s) noexcept                     { cout<<"Move constructor"<<endl; }
    auto operator= (MyClass const& s)     -> MyClass& { cout<<"Copy Assignment"<<endl; return *this; }
    auto operator= (MyClass&& s) noexcept -> MyClass& { cout<<"Move assignment"<<endl; return *this; }
    ~MyClass()                                        { cout<<"Destructor"<<endl; }
    shared_ptr<MyClass> next;
};

void funct(shared_ptr<MyClass> & cl1){
    shared_ptr<MyClass> cl2 = make_shared<MyClass>();
    cout<<"**init cl2**"<<endl;
    cout<<"address cl2 points to: "<<cl2.get()<<endl;
    cout<<"count reference of cl2: "<<cl2.use_count()<<endl;
    cout<<"**link cl2 <-> cl1**"<<endl;
    cl2->next = cl1;
    cl1->next = cl2;
    cout<<"address cl1 points to:  "<<cl1.get()<<endl;
    cout<<"count reference of cl1: "<<cl1.use_count()<<endl;
    cout<<"address cl2 points to:  "<<cl2.get()<<endl;
    cout<<"count reference of cl2: "<<cl2.use_count()<<endl;
    // cl2 is deleted after exit of this function
}

int main()
{
    cout<<"Size of MyClass "<<sizeof(MyClass)<<endl;

    cout<<"**init cl2**"<<endl;
    shared_ptr<MyClass> cl1 = make_shared<MyClass>();

    funct(cl1);

    cout<<"**cl2 is destroy**"<<endl;
    cout<<"count reference of cl1: "<<cl1.use_count()<<endl;
    cout<<"count reference of cl1->next "<<cl1->next.use_count()<<endl;
    cout<<"address cl1->next points to "<<cl1->next<<endl;   // print the object's address where cl2 points at.  
    return 0;
}
```

Console Ouput:

```
Size of MyClass 16
**init cl2**
Default constructor
Default constructor
**init cl2**
address cl2 points to: 0x503000000050
count reference of cl2: 1
**link cl2 <-> cl1**
address cl1 points to:  0x503000000020
count reference of cl1: 2
address cl2 points to:  0x503000000050
count reference of cl2: 2
**cl2 is destroy**
count reference of cl1: 2
count reference of cl1->next 1
address cl1->next points to 0x503000000050
Program stderr

=================================================================
==1==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks
Indirect leak of 32 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x55ea5a0f420d in operator new(unsigned long) /root/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/asan/asan_new_delete.cpp:95:3
    #1 0x55ea5a0f8717 in std::__new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<MyClass, std::allocator<void>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/new_allocator.h:147:27
    #2 0x55ea5a0f8293 in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<MyClass, std::allocator<void>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>>>::allocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<MyClass, std::allocator<void>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>>&, unsigned long) /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/alloc_traits.h:482:20
    #3 0x55ea5a0f8293 in std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<MyClass, std::allocator<void>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>>> std::__allocate_guarded<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<MyClass, std::allocator<void>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>>>(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<MyClass, std::allocator<void>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>>&) /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/allocated_ptr.h:98:21
    #4 0x55ea5a0f7fd8 in std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<MyClass, std::allocator<void>>(MyClass*&, std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<void>>) /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:969:19
    #5 0x55ea5a0f7d94 in std::__shared_ptr<MyClass, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<void>>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<void>>) /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1712:14
    #6 0x55ea5a0f7b9f in std::shared_ptr<MyClass>::shared_ptr<std::allocator<void>>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<void>>) /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/shared_ptr.h:464:4
    #7 0x55ea5a0f6e72 in std::shared_ptr<std::enable_if<!is_array<MyClass>::value, MyClass>::type> std::make_shared<MyClass>() /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/shared_ptr.h:1009:14
    #8 0x55ea5a0f65de in funct(std::shared_ptr<MyClass>&) /app/example.cpp:17:31
    #9 0x55ea5a0f6ad9 in main /app/example.cpp:38:5
    #10 0x7f80ea002082 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x24082) (BuildId: 1878e6b475720c7c51969e69ab2d276fae6d1dee)

Indirect leak of 32 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x55ea5a0f420d in operator new(unsigned long) /root/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/asan/asan_new_delete.cpp:95:3
    #1 0x55ea5a0f8717 in std::__new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<MyClass, std::allocator<void>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/new_allocator.h:147:27
    #2 0x55ea5a0f8293 in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<MyClass, std::allocator<void>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>>>::allocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<MyClass, std::allocator<void>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>>&, unsigned long) /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/alloc_traits.h:482:20
    #3 0x55ea5a0f8293 in std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<MyClass, std::allocator<void>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>>> std::__allocate_guarded<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<MyClass, std::allocator<void>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>>>(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<MyClass, std::allocator<void>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>>&) /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/allocated_ptr.h:98:21
    #4 0x55ea5a0f7fd8 in std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<MyClass, std::allocator<void>>(MyClass*&, std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<void>>) /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:969:19
    #5 0x55ea5a0f7d94 in std::__shared_ptr<MyClass, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<void>>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<void>>) /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1712:14
    #6 0x55ea5a0f7b9f in std::shared_ptr<MyClass>::shared_ptr<std::allocator<void>>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<void>>) /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/shared_ptr.h:464:4
    #7 0x55ea5a0f6e72 in std::shared_ptr<std::enable_if<!is_array<MyClass>::value, MyClass>::type> std::make_shared<MyClass>() /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/shared_ptr.h:1009:14
    #8 0x55ea5a0f6acd in main /app/example.cpp:36:31
    #9 0x7f80ea002082 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x24082) (BuildId: 1878e6b475720c7c51969e69ab2d276fae6d1dee)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 64 byte(s) leaked in 2 allocation(s).
```

Other answer explain that the leak occurs because "they [the object] have pointers to each other which keeps them alive." I don't understand that well - meaning I don't understand the C++ mechanism or rules that "pointer keeps them alive". I output the ownership count of each object here.

**Question 1**: Why do `cl1` still have ownership of 2 when `cl2` is already gone after `funct` returns? In other words, who have the ownership of the object the cl1 points to beside cl1 pointer?

**Question 2**: someone commented that when I have `cl1->next = cl2`, a copy of the smart-pointer object is created. When the life-time of the variable cl2 ends, the copy still lives, and points to the very same memory. Would someone be able to prove that?

I edited my program to have both copy and assignment constructor. I see that nothing is printed out beside the default constructor.

If both the cl2 pointer itself and the memory where it points to is deallocated, then who else is `cl1->next`? Anyhow, I don't see any destructor is called. The address where cl2 points to at still lives, as printed out in main, near the end of the program.

```
cout<<"address cl1->next points to "<<cl1->next<<endl;   // print the object's address where cl2 points at.
```

What I have tried:

- I tried to create circular reference between 2 objects.
- I print out ownership to check if the ownership changes and could go to zero when the program exists.
- I check the indirect leak size expect that each leak should be same as the object size. But each leak is twice the object size. Total leak is 4 times the object size.

Comment: With `cl1->next = cl2` you create a *copy* of the smart-pointer object. When the life-time of the variable `cl2` ends, the copy still lives, and points to the very same memory. If you check `cl1->next.use_count()` when back in the `main` function, you should notice that it's `1`.

Comment: *"Why do `cl1` still have ownership of 2 when `cl2` is already gone"* -- Why does this look like a problem to you? If two people (let's call them "Clark1" and "Claire2") own a company (let's call the company "Two"), and one of them retires, would you expect that to force the other person to retire?

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions, it's a bad fit for a site where you can only accept one answer. And, hint: examine the value of `cl1->next` after the function returns.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have edited the question a bit to clarify and address the main issue I want to ask. What still have ownership of the object where cl2 originally point to. 

I made copy and assignment constructor to see if there is any copy of the MyClass object, but there is none printed out. 

Why isn't destructor of cl2 is called?

Comment: That's kind of the point of a *shared ownership* structure like `std::shared_ptr`. You can have multiple owners to a single resource, and if one owner releases its ownership (like when `cl2` is destructed) the resource still lives on because there are other owners.

Comment: Perhaps it might be easier to visualize if you draw it using pen and paper? Draw three labeled boxes on a paper, label one `cl2`, one `cl1->next` and the last one `MyClass object`. Draw an arrow from `cl2` to `MyClass object`, and also draw an arrow from `cl1->next` to `MyClass object`. That's kind of how the ownership and sharing of the `MyClass` object is. When later `cl2` is destructed, you can erase that box and its arrow from the drawing (or redraw without `cl2`), you see that the object still exists and with a live pointer to it.